# Gitlab Omnibus: Delete backup from Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-s3, cron, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

I would like to delete the back up files that is older than 1 week.  I have followed this [backup document](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/raketasks/backup_restore.md) from gitlab and successfully create the backup files to upload to Amazon S3.

I have also set up `gitlab_rails['backup_keep_time'] = 604800` but it does not work.

However, from what I observe in the IAM user policy they created.  There is no authorization to delete the files.

The backup files are packing up and I would not want to do this manually in AWS.

Is there any standard way to delete the backup files in Amazon S3 for gitlab omnibus package?

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1412062044000",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
        "s3:GetBucketAcl",
        "s3:GetBucketLocation",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:GetObjectAcl",
        "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:PutObjectAcl"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::my.s3.bucket/*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1412062097000",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetBucketLocation",
        "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1412062128000",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListBucket"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::my.s3.bucket"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use S3 lifecycle policy by Following steps:

1. Click on your S3 property and select Lifecycle tab and click Add rule.

   [image: Step 1]
2. Click on Configure Rule.

   [image: Step 2]
3. Check permanently delete and enter seven days(or any other number you want) and click on review.

   [image: Step 3]
4. Enter rule name and click on "create and activate rule".

   [image: Step 4]
5. Check your rule created successfully and enjoy.

   [image: Step 5]

Answer (score 1):

If you are only interested in purging old backups in the s3 bucket you can achieve this directly in AWS. On the s3 bucket properties you can set up a lifecycle policy to expire files older than a specified number of days or move to glacier which is much cheaper.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the backup_keep_time configuration option only manages local files. GitLab does not automatically prune old files stored in a third-party object storage (e.g., AWS S3)...

https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/raketasks/backup_restore.html